# vnstat: print current network activity to a file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, bash

How can i print the output of `vnstat -l` to a file?
what i've tried:

```
vnstat -l &> file
```

but it just hangsup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `l` option. From the `vnstat` man page:

```
   -l, --live mode
          Display current transfer rate for the selected interface in real time until interrupted. Statis‐
          tics  will be shown after interruption if the runtime was more than 10 seconds. An optional mode
          parameter can be used to select between the displaying of packets per second (mode 0) and trans‐
          fer  counters  (mode  1) during execution.  --style can also be used to affect the layout of the
          output.
```

So, the `-l` makes `vnstat` display output in "live mode", constantly updating, that's why you can't capture the output. If you want an easily parseable format use

```
vnstat --dumpdb
```

To just save the standard output do

```
vnstat > log.txt
```

---

If what you want is the current upload and download rate, `vnstat` is not the right tool for the job. Try `sar` from the `sysstat` package (see man `sar` for more info):

```
sudo apt-get install sysstat 
sudo sar -n DEV 1 1
```

To extract the current* download and upload rate for the interface `wlan0` from `sar`'s output do:

```
sudo sar -n DEV 1 1 | grep wlan0 | tail -n 1 | gawk '{print "Down: "$5,"Up: "$6}'
```

* What does "current" mean? `sar` (and any other method) will take some milliseconds to generate output.

Comment: but i actually need the total current network activity. this will print stats of today, yesterday, this month etc

Comment: What do you mean? What is "current" network activity? You mean the upload/download _rate_?

Comment: yes. upload/download...

Comment: See updated answer, vnstat is not the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to print just final summary to file from some period you are going to monitor network activity, but you can cheat it this way:

```
vnstat -l -i <device> >> dump.txt
```

The only issue is that vnstat will write output to file every second so it is not the most convenient way. For continuous monitoring with log for every second or so terdon answered your question.

Comment: Ok, but be aware of the problem that `vnstat` overwrites the status line again and again using backspaces so in the output you will se only the last status. You can replace the sequences of backspaces and expand the statuses to individual lines using for example: `sed -re $'s/\b[\b ]+\b/\\n/g' dump.txt`

Comment: Tnak's for a good trick ;)